# Why does my query keeps on throwing an error message "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Orders" "?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE "Orders" (
"row_id" INT PRIMARY KEY,
"order_id" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
"created_at" DATE NOT NULL,
"item_id" VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
"quantity" INT NOT NULL,
"cust_id" INT NOT NULL,
"delivery" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
"add_id" INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "Customer" (
"cust_id" int NOT NULL,
"cust_firstname" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"cust_latname" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_Customer" PRIMARY KEY (
"cust_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "address" (
"add_id" int NOT NULL,
"delivery_address1" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"delivery_address2" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"delivery_city" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
"delivery_zipcode" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_address" PRIMARY KEY (
"add_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "item" (
"item_id" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"sku" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"item_name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
"item_cat" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"item_price" decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_item" PRIMARY KEY (
"item_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "ingredient" (
"ing_id" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"ing_name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
"ing_weight" int NOT NULL,
"ing_mass" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"ing_price" decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_ingredient" PRIMARY KEY (
"ing_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "recipe" (
"row_id" int NOT NULL,
"recipe_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"ing_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"quantity" int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_recipe" PRIMARY KEY (
"row_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "inventory" (
"inv_id" int NOT NULL,
"item_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"quantity" int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_inventory" PRIMARY KEY (
"inv_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "shift" (
"shift_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"day_of_week" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"start_time" time NOT NULL,
"end_time" time NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_shift" PRIMARY KEY (
"shift_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "rota" (
"row_id" int NOT NULL,
"rota_id" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"date" date NOT NULL,
"shift_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"staff_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "pk_rota" PRIMARY KEY (
"row_id"
)
);

CREATE TABLE "staff" (
"staff_id" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"first_name" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
"start_time" time NOT NULL,
"end_time" time NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "pk_staff" PRIMARY KEY("staff_id")
);

ALTER TABLE "rota" ADD CONSTRAINT "unique_date" UNIQUE("date");
ALTER TABLE "Orders" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_Orders_created_at" FOREIGN KEY("created_at")
REFERENCES "rota" ("date");
ALTER TABLE "Orders" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_Orders_item_id" FOREIGN KEY("item_id")
REFERENCES "item" ("item_id");
ALTER TABLE "Orders" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_Orders_add_id" FOREIGN KEY("add_id")
REFERENCES "address" ("add_id");
ALTER TABLE "Customer" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_Customer_cust_id" FOREIGN KEY("cust_id")
REFERENCES "Orders" ("cust_id");
ALTER TABLE "ingredient" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_ingredient_ing_id" FOREIGN KEY("ing_id")
REFERENCES "recipe" ("ing_id");
ALTER TABLE "recipe" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_recipe_recipe_id" FOREIGN KEY("recipe_id")
REFERENCES "item" ("sku");
ALTER TABLE "recipe" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_recipe_ing_id" FOREIGN KEY("ing_id")
REFERENCES "inventory" ("item_id");
ALTER TABLE "rota" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rota_shift_id" FOREIGN KEY("shift_id")
REFERENCES "shift" ("shift_id");
ALTER TABLE "staff" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_staff_staff_id" FOREIGN KEY("staff_id")
REFERENCES "rota" ("staff_id");
```

I am trying to link the customer and oders table using cust_id as the linking field

Comment: Please reduce the code to only include neded statements

Comment: So many blank rows and very difficult to read!

Comment: A foreign key must reference a (complete) key - either a primary key or a unique constraint.

Comment: You can't have a customer without an order? Should it not be the other way around? If you want to do it that way customer must be unique in orders and consequently a customer can have at most one order

Comment: Do you have any specific question about all these queries?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

All constraints - but the ones that follow - seem to be OK. Read comments:

```
SQL> -- Should be vice versa - "Orders" should reference "Customer"
SQL> -- ALTER TABLE "Customer" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_Customer_cust_id" FOREIGN KEY("cust_id")
SQL> -- REFERENCES "Orders" ("cust_id");
SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE "Orders" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_orders_cust_id" FOREIGN KEY ("cust_id")
  2  REFERENCES "Customer" ("cust_id");

Table altered.
```

---

```
SQL> -- Should be vice versa - "recipe" should reference "ingredient"
SQL> -- ALTER TABLE "ingredient" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_ingredient_ing_id" FOREIGN KEY("ing_id")
SQL> -- REFERENCES "recipe" ("ing_id");
SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE "recipe" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_recipe_ing_id" FOREIGN KEY ("ing_id")
  2  REFERENCES "ingredient" ("ing_id");

Table altered.
```

---

```
SQL> -- I don't know what is this supposed to do. This way it won't work, and it won't work
SQL> -- vice versa either
SQL> --ALTER TABLE "recipe" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_recipe_recipe_id" FOREIGN KEY("recipe_id")
SQL> --REFERENCES "item" ("sku");
```

---

```
SQL> -- Doesn't make sense to me. I'd rather reference "item" from "inventory"; what does "recipe"
SQL> -- have to do with it?
SQL> -- ALTER TABLE "recipe" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_recipe_ing_id" FOREIGN KEY("ing_id")
SQL> -- REFERENCES "inventory" ("item_id");
SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE "inventory" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_inventory_item_id" FOREIGN KEY ("item_id")
  2  REFERENCES "item" ("item_id");

Table altered.
```

---

```
SQL> -- What is "rota"? Probably should also be vice-versa as several other constraints:
SQL> --ALTER TABLE "staff" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_staff_staff_id" FOREIGN KEY("staff_id")
SQL> --REFERENCES "rota" ("staff_id");
SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE "rota" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rota_staff_id" FOREIGN KEY ("staff_id")
  2  REFERENCES "staff" ("staff_id");

Table altered.

SQL>
```